# Rails 4 / NodeJS / 'autodetect' “Could not find a JavaScript runtime”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

Hi everyone I am having a very frustrating issue at the moment. Everything seemed to be working fine until I tried to run a rake db:migrate and it fails saying 'autodetect' : Could not find a JavaScript runtime. So I thought maybe it was something on my Windows machine and restarted now I cant even start my rails app with a "rails s" because I get the same error message. After googling around I see people suggesting installing nodejs and the gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby.

I already had both of them installed on my machine and appear to be working. Has anyone else had this happen? Im on windows 7 and here is my gem file.

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'pg'  
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem "jquery-fileupload-rails" 
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'tinymce-rails' 
gem 'devise'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.9'
gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
```

and here is the error message

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-1.2.4/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:45:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

Comment: `therubyracer` and `libv8` are major pain in the ass in developing windows. I would suggest installing libv8 somehow first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help out. I googled a bit for libv8 and was able to install with `gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8`, but no change. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Visit `https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs` as suggested and try installing any of the listed runtimes (for example Node.js)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.

In the end in order to fix this I uninstalled and re installed the railsinstaller. Based on another stack overflow answer where the person fixed this issue by formatting their HDD, a bit of overkill... but anyways that fixed the issue.